# How to create a dictionary list of key: value items and append it to the original list in Ansible?

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, key-value

I want to create a new dictionary list, 'path: value' to be looped for each user and appended under each item in the user list. The end result would look something like below:

```
        "userdata": [
            {
                "ClassType": "Full Time",
                "FirstName": "Grace",
                "LastName": "Higgins",
                "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Part Time",
                "FirstName": "Robert",
                "LastName": "Miller",
                "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Flexi",
                "FirstName": "Jeffrey",
                "LastName": "Keller",
                "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
            }
        ]
```

The values for path is dependent on the value of the ClassType.

However, when I tried to append the new path: value dictionary list to the original userdata list, the 'path: item.path' is in the wrong layout and also has the wrong value:

```
TASK [Read_csv_creation : Append to original userdata list] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': '}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "userdata": [
            {
                "ClassType": "Full Time",
                "FirstName": "Grace",
                "LastName": "Higgins"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Part Time",
                "FirstName": "Robert",
                "LastName": "Miller"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Flexi",
                "FirstName": "Jeffrey",
                "LastName": "Keller"
            },
            "path: item.path"
        ]
    },
```

How can I get the final output as shown below?

```
        "userdata": [
            {
                "ClassType": "Full Time",
                "FirstName": "Grace",
                "LastName": "Higgins",
                "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Part Time",
                "FirstName": "Robert",
                "LastName": "Miller",
                "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Flexi",
                "FirstName": "Jeffrey",
                "LastName": "Keller",
                "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
            }
        ]
```

---

Below is my tasks file. The variable 'data_list' would be my original list.

```
    - name: Read input file
      read_csv:
        path: /var/lib/awx/projects/file/creation.csv
        key: FirstName 
        fieldnames: FirstName,LastName,ClassType
        delimiter: ','
      register: userdata

    - name: Initialise data list
      set_fact:
        data_list: []

    - name: Extract the list
      set_fact:
        data_list: "{{ data_list + [{ 'FirstName': item.FirstName, 'LastName': item.LastName, 'ClassType': item.ClassType }] }}"
      loop: "{{ userdata | community.general.json_query('dict.[*][0]') }}"

    - name: Set fact for data_list
      set_fact: 
        data_list: "{{ data_list[1:] }}"

    - name: If class is full time
      set_fact:
        path: "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
      when: item.ClassType == "Full Time"  
      loop: "{{ data_list  }}"   

    - name: If employment type is part time
      set_fact:
        path: "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
      when: item.ClassType == "Part Time"  
      loop: "{{ data_list  }}"   

    - name: If employment type is flexi
      set_fact:
        path: "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
      when: item.ClassType == "Flexi"  
      loop: "{{ data_list  }}"   

    - name: Append to original userdata list
      set_fact:
        userdata: "{{ data_list + ['path: item.path'] }}"
      loop: "{{ data_list  }}"
```

The job run output is as below. I have omitted some of it as it is very lengthy:

```
TASK [Read_csv_creation : Initialise data list] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "data_list": []
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Read_csv_creation : Read input file] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "dict": {
        " FirstName ": {
            "ClassType": " Employment Type ",
            "FirstName": " FirstName ",
            "LastName": " Last Name "
        },
        "Grace": {
            "ClassType": "Sub Contract",
            "FirstName": "Grace",
            "LastName": "Higgins"
        },
        "Robert": {
            "ClassType": "Contract",
            "FirstName": "Robert",
            "LastName": "Miller"
        },
        "Jeffrey": {
            "ClassType": "Full Time",
            "FirstName": "Jeffrey",
            "LastName": "Keller"
        }
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "delimiter": ",",
            "dialect": "excel",
            "fieldnames": [
                "FirstName",
                "LastName",
                "ClassType"
            ],
            "key": "FirstName",
            "path": "/var/lib/awx/projects/file/creation.csv",
            "skipinitialspace": null,
            "strict": null,
            "unique": true
        }
    },
    "list": []
}

TASK [Read_csv_creation : Extract the list] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': ' FirstName ', 'LastName': ' Last Name ', 'ClassType': ' Class Type '}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "data_list": [
            {
                "ClassType": " Class Type ",
                "FirstName": " FirstName ",
                "LastName": " Last Name "
            }
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "ClassType": " Class Type ",
        "FirstName": " FirstName ",
        "LastName": " Last Name ",
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': '}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "data_list": [
            {
                "ClassType": " Class Type ",
                "FirstName": " FirstName ",
                "LastName": " Last Name ",

            }
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "ClassType": "Class Time",
        "FirstName": "Grace",
        "LastName": "Higgins"
    }
}


TASK [Read_csv_creation : Set fact for data_list] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "data_list": [
            {
                "ClassType": "Full Time",
                "FirstName": "Grace",
                "LastName": "Higgins"
            },
            {
                "ClassType": "Part Time",
                "FirstName": "Robert",
                "LastName": "Miller"
            },
            {
                "EmploymentType": "Flexi",
                "FirstName": "Jeffrey",
                "LastName": "Keller"
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}


TASK [Read_csv_creation : If class type is full time] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': 'Grace', 'LastName': 'Higgins', 'ClassType': 'Full Time'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "ClassType": "Full Time",
        "FirstName": "Grace",
        "LastName": "Higgins"
    }
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': 'Robert', 'LastName': 'Miller', 'ClassType': 'Part Time'})  => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "EmploymentType": "Contract",
        "FirstName": "Robert",
        "LastName": "Miller"
    },
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': .....
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        .......
        "ClassType": "Flexi"
    },
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file for [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) testing

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/creation.csv 
Grace,Higgins,Full Time
Robert,Miller,Part Time
Jeffrey,Keller,Flexi
```

read the CSV file

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/creation.csv
        # key: FirstName 
        fieldnames: FirstName,LastName,ClassType
        delimiter: ','
      register: userdata
```

When you omit the parameter *key* you get the list without 'extracting'

```yaml
  userdata.list:
  - ClassType: Full Time
    FirstName: Grace
    LastName: Higgins
  - ClassType: Part Time
    FirstName: Robert
    LastName: Miller
  - ClassType: Flexi
    FirstName: Jeffrey
    LastName: Keller
```

To add the attribute *path* create the dictionary *class_path*

```yaml
  class_path:
    Full Time: "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    Part Time: "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    Flexi: "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
```

From the list *map* the attribute *ClassType*, *extract* the *path*, and create the list of the hashes

```yaml
  path: "{{ userdata.list|map(attribute='ClassType')|
                          map('extract', class_path)|
                          map('community.general.dict_kv', 'path') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  path:
  - path: OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
  - path: OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
  - path: OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
```

*zip* the lists and *combine* the items. You have to use *set_facts* because the variable *userdata* has already been used in [*registered vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        userdata: "{{ userdata.list|zip(path)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  userdata:
  - ClassType: Full Time
    FirstName: Grace
    LastName: Higgins
    path: OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
  - ClassType: Part Time
    FirstName: Robert
    LastName: Miller
    path: OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
  - ClassType: Flexi
    FirstName: Jeffrey
    LastName: Keller
    path: OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    class_path:
      Full Time: "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
      Part Time: "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
      Flexi: "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"

    path: "{{ userdata.list|map(attribute='ClassType')|
                            map('extract', class_path)|
                            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'path') }}"

  tasks:

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/creation.csv
        # key: FirstName 
        fieldnames: FirstName,LastName,ClassType
        delimiter: ','
      register: userdata

    - debug:
        var: userdata.list
    - debug:
        var: path

    - set_fact:
        userdata: "{{ userdata.list|zip(path)|map('combine') }}"
    - debug:
        var: userdata
```